# How to iterate over a Map that contains List Objects as value and get those as a separate List Object using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

There are two classes:

```
public class Company {
    
    String name;
    int regId;
    List<Employee> employee;

    //getters and setters
    //constructor
}
```

```
public class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    // getters and setters
    // constructor
}
```

There is a `Map<String, Company>`, String as key and object of type Company as value.
Company contains List of Employee as one of its member objects.

Now I have to iterate over the Map and get List of Employee from each of the Company objects and add it to a separate ArrayList object.

I am not sure how to get Employee List of Object by iterating through the map using the Streams concept and store it as a separate ArrayList.

Any suggestions on the same?

Comment: `map.values().stream().flatMap(v -> v.getEmployees().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())`?

Comment: @Vishal Do you want all employees in one big list?

Comment: @BuildSlayer - Yeah All the employees in one ArrayList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
Map<String, Company> stringCompanyMap = new HashMap<>();
stringCompanyMap.put("Dsa", new Company("Nike", 1, Arrays.asList(
        new Employee(1, "Jordan"),
        new Employee(2, "Mike"))));
stringCompanyMap.put("Sd", new Company("Adidas", 1, Arrays.asList(
        new Employee(3, "Tyson"),
        new Employee(4, "Russel"))));

List<Employee> allEmployees = stringCompanyMap.values().stream()
        .flatMap(company -> company.employee.stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(allEmployees);
```

Output:

```
[Employee(id=3, name=Tyson), Employee(id=4, name=Russel), Employee(id=1, name=Jordan), Employee(id=2, name=Mike)]
```

Comment: Using the above code, the first Employee object is getting stored in List twice and then the rest of the objects. For example: if there are two values in Map(Company 1 , Company 2) and Company 1 has Employee E1 and Company 2 has Employee E2, it is getting stored as <E1,E1,E2>

Comment: @Vishal Unless an employee works in two companies, it doesn't happen. I have edited to demonstrate it.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved using this as well :-

```
List<List<Employee>> tempEmployeesList;  //Temporary list for holding list of list of Employees
List<Employee>  empList = new ArrayList<>(); //Actual list for holding list of all employees in the Companies present in map values.

tempEmployeesList = map.values().stream().map(x -> x.getEmployee()).collect(Collectors.toList());
tempEmployeesList.forEach(empList::addAll); 
System.out.println(empList);
```